# Message After Download

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I've a Servlet that makes and returns a zip file
Something like this

```
 response.setHeader("Pragma","Public");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0");

            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");

            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
            if(file.getName().contains("–")){
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"file.zip\"");
            }

            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(os);
            for (File f : files) {
                //add files, it's working...
                }
                bis.close();
                fis.close();
                zos.closeEntry();
            }
            zos.flush();
            zos.close();
            os.flush();
            os.close();
```

Currently to download I'm using a iframe, so I set src attribute to start download.
The download frame loads when call this function

```
function loadIDownloadFrame(url) {
    document.getElementById("idownloadFrame").src=url;
}
```

But now, I need show a message after return the zip file without leaving current page. I need to know if the servlet returned the zip file.

I tried get iframe status with "window.frames['idownloadFrame'].document.readyState", but always status is "complete".

Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You makes no sense.

Comment: I need to create a "multiple download", I have in one folder 6000+ files, so the compression process is slow and I need to show a loading during it... How I close the loading?

Comment: @Lucas Merencia: You should rethink this, zipping 6k+ files synchronously will kill your server(s) under load, just consider how the amount of memory (RAM) and/or network IO. Let the user trigger a job and return a transaction ID to the browser, then use some JS function to trigger the job status. If the job finished offer a download button (this is a very high-level description)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could directly refer to download link to mapped Servlet(which returns the downloadable binary). It would not change the page if you set appropriate header in the mapped servlet to return the binary, from the code snippet it looks like you are doing that already. Why do you have to have file download in a different iframe? You don't necessarily need that.

Where do you have to show the message? Like a JavaScript alert or something?

Comment: Actually, I need close a loading when the compression process finishes.

Comment: I think you should think of a different strategy to do this, like make it asynchronous. With your current approach you would hog a connection everytime the user tries to download. You should rather spawn a thread and complete the request ASAP with some response code indicating that currently files are getting compressed.